# What would cause curl POST with --data and @filename to only send 46% of the data?

Tags: http, curl, post, go

I run:

`curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" --data @race.mov "http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/put_file"`

where race.mov is 4134329 bytes. But only 1931871 are received by the program listening on port 8080.

so I try another file that's 2482905 bytes. But only 1150635 are received. Isn't that weird?

`irb(main):002:0> 1931871.0 / 4134329.0
=> 0.4672755845023461
irb(main):003:0> 1150635.0 / 2482905.0
=> 0.4634228856923644`

What's going on to make curl only send 46% of the binary data?

Update this same go program:

```
  dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/Users/aa/Movies/race.mov")
  fmt.Println(err)

  endpoint := fmt.Sprintf("http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/put_file")
  fmt.Println(endpoint)
  buffer_reader := bytes.NewReader(dat)
  resp, err := http.Post(endpoint, "application/octet-stream", buffer_reader)
  fmt.Println(resp, err)
```

makes the correct length happen so it MUST be curl

Comment: Can you try `-H 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' --upload-file race.mov`?

Comment: wow, --upload-file works perfect. Didn't even need transfer-encoding. Well done.